# Left Outer Joins with Linq extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq

Could you help me to translate this Linq query to extension methods:

```
    var query = from person in people
                join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
                from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { person.FirstName, PetName = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.Name) };
```

The query come from [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx#Anchor_0) about Left outer join.

I already did this:

```
    var result = people.join(pets, x, y => y.Owner, (x, y) => {
                    x.FirstName,
                    PetName = y == null ? String.Empty : y.Name
                }).ToList();
```

But I don't know what to do with the `DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Adding the `DefaultIfEmpty()` as explained on other solutions result in CS0746 Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: Why do you have to use method syntax?  joins are _much_ cleaner in query syntax and method syntax gives you no benefit in terms of performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this with `GroupJoin`

```
people.GroupJoin(pets,p => p,pt => pt.Owner,
                 (p, pt) => new { p.FirstName, names = pt.Select(y => y.Name)})
      .SelectMany(p => p.names.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => new {p.FirstName,PetName=x}))
```